# Force Firefox To Open In One Tab For Only That Window

Tags: firefox, browser-tabs

Like the title says, I'm looking for a way (whether by command-line argument, option, or plugin) which will allow me to force firefox to open all tabs in the same tab, but only for that specific window.

For example, I have Firefox open with GMail.  When I open a new window (however it happens), I go to google.com.  When I then open a new tab and go to wikipedia.org, I want wikipedia to open in the google tab.  [There is way to do this in about:config](http://boredandblogging.com/2007/02/10/firefox-force-all-links-to-open-in-tabs/), but it seems to be browser-wide in all windows.

Ideally I'd like a command-line argument which will open a new window and have only that window open all tabs in the same tab.  I'm not sure if this is even possible, but any help would be appreciated.

Comment: If I understood right, you want to disable tabs. One window, one thing in it ... and that's it ? Correct ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at the following Firefox addon: [Tab Mix Plus](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/1122)